# How to update summary state of data changes without subscribing to every input/component change in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a rather complex modal to manage some data state. It has a lot of inputs, selections, checkboxes and other custom components.

Now I would like to show the user some summary hints about what data has been updated during the time modal has been opened and what consequences it would lead.
For example, on some actions, I would like to change the color of the "Update" button, on some actions not to show it at all and for all states show some summary (in a tooltip, for example) of what has been changed. Important thing is that it's not just showing that some input fileds were touched and others not, it's again some combination of their state change.

The problem that I don't use `<form>` tag at all since most of custom components just don't have name attributes to support it. So I can't write a custom form validator, the main side effect of which will be updating state summary variable (since I need something more complex that just form valid-invalid summary flag).

I also consider an approach of attaching valueChange or ngModelChange callbacks to all inputs and components to be rather complex in implementation at the current state of development.

So there is a question how can I continuously update state summary variable based on data change.

I could use setInterval() to update state but its update delay will be something completely arbitrary from the angular update cycle.

Update state result is used in several places so creating just a function calculating it on request and putting it in all needed places is very ineffective.
I've tried a hack to use such function only in one place, put the result in a variable and in all other places use the variable but it leads to angular smth like "variable is updated after it was used" error.

Is there any better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should use reactive forms. It makes it easier to track changes and manage controls.

With that in mind, start by creating a default value for your form :

```
defaultFormValue = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };
```

Then create a form from it :

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group(this.defaultFormValue);
```

Now you can use all of the reactive forms methods & properties to manage your form

```
get isFirstNameChanged() {
  return this.myForm.get('firstName').dirty;
}

get isFirstNameDifferentThanDefault() {
  return this.myForm.get('firstName').value !== this.defaultFormValue.firstName;
} 

resetForm() {
  this.myForm.reset(this.defaultFormValue);
}

// etc.
```

Comment: @ArseniiFomin you do not need a form tag.

Comment: To do the task I need to create form group since without form group it's the same thing as providing manual listener to every component change. But to create form group, I need something like: <form [formGroup]="mainForm"> and here we go.

Comment: @ArseniiFomin no, form groups can be applied to anything, not only forms. So here we not go.

Comment: It's not about form only. What requirements on underlying components do reactive forms have? Most of my components don't have name, some of them have ngModel but other use value/valueChange to pass state inside/outside. I'm not sure this can be used with reactive data pass.

Comment: Look, you ask for a solution, I give you one. Looking at the other answer, all I see is the same. If you're too stubborn to accept it, then suit yourself, but stop giving false excuse one after another, just say so. Anyway, that's the best practice here, so if you don't want it, then just wait for another answer.

Comment: What I need is understanding what in reality will have to be changed in my app which is half a year under development and already live for your solution to work. Naturally, underwater rocks of any approach are not evident from reading the documentation. I can just blindly start to rework everything to reactive forms which eventually can take from a few days to a week of work just to understand that something has broken completely and all changes should be reverted. That's why I asking more questions the people that evidently know more in this field. You can call me stubborn, of course.

Comment: Template driven and reactive forms both have their own purpose. You've chosen the wrong one 1.5y ago. Because you poorly coded and implemented a bad design, doesn't mean you should keep going this way and f*ck your application up. If you're backing up from work because there's too much to do, that's your issue. But the solution is the reactive forms. Otherwise, you sure can keep doing things poorly, and use `NgControl` to double the amount of code for the same result. Anyway, since you clearly don't want my solution, I'm not needed here. Good luck with your issue, see you around !

Answer (score 1):

I second Maryannah's idea of switching to reactive forms, with the addition of subscribing to the form's `valueChanges` Observable (or that of any form control) and using RxJS operators as required. For example:

```
// watch first name field for changes
this.userForm.get('firstName').valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(newFirstNameValue => {
    // do stuff with new value here
});

// watch whole form for compound checks
this.userForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    map(formData => { 
        importantCheckbox: formData.importantCheckbox,
        desiredInput: formData.desiredInput
    })
).subscribe(formData => {
    // react to compound check here
});
```

RxJS is incredibly powerful in this kind of situation. Definitely something to look into.

Comment: If I had such a task for all the forms in the application I have, maybe reworking all the custom components to move to reactive forms would be reasonable. But I need only one place in the app that really needs to track changes and reworking everything for it is too much. I can't use <form> tag so neither template nor reactive forms are applicable for me.

Comment: Instead, you could create an Observable using the `fromEvent` operator on the inputs' change events, which would then allow you to chain the various RxJS operators, filtering out anything you don't need. It's a more roundabout approach, but it may be your best bet if you can't use `<form>` tags.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However, I don't understand why I should use Observable in such a simple case (no data loading from the backend). If I have to touch every element manually, I can just add (ngModelChange)="updateState()" or its analogues to the everything

Comment: Observables allow you to add operators. In essence it's the same thing, but you have much more control: `debounceTime`, `distinctUntilChanged`…Observables are probably the most flexible tool in the Angular toolkit, they're awesome for pretty much everything, and don't really add complexity.